# Protruding Gas Pipe

Tags: kitchens, pipe, gas, oven, renovation

I live in an old NYC Co-op and looking to do a small kitchen Reno. The gas line protrudes out of the wall which doesn’t allow my oven to sit flush against the wall.
My super said, If we were to change or alter the gas line, it would need to be shut off for the entire building and once reconnected each unit will need to be inspected. Can anyone confirm this?
Any suggestions to work around the gas line that will allow my oven to fit against the wall?
Thanks in advance for any tips.

Comment: I'm correct in assuming that this gas line's shutoff valve is part of the branch that you intend to remove?

Comment: As an anecdote to this situation, many years ago (~40), I was helping renovate some Habitat apartments in NYC on a youth trip.  A similar scenario to this, but the gas to a stove needed to be either connected or disconnected (I don't remember which).  The guy who did it (obviously a "handyman"), just opened a window, and quickly made the change needed.  Even then, I thought it was a stupid idea to work on live gas lines, but if there isn't a local shutoff (which there should be at every gas appliance), sometimes unsafe decisions are made.  Fortunately, no accident happened, at least this time.

Comment: Why not pick a hypothetical plumber to do the work and ask him? I can't imagine that your by-laws (or whatever governs your co-op) in NYC allow you to work on your own gas lines anyway.

Comment: As you can see, you've gotten two good answers to your first question - is this code? Your second question should be just that, a second click of the "ask question" button, because nobody's really addressed that part. If you [edit] it out of this question, then ask a whole new question about it, you'll get a good answer there. Read up on [how to ask a good question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is a common practice that after gas has been shut off to a building, when the gas is restored, each gas appliance should be checked.

Some gas appliances utilize a standing pilot flame as the ignition source when the appliance cycles on. The gas fueling the pilot *should* be controlled by a safety mechanism such as a thermocouple so that if the pilot is extinguished, the gas supplying it will be automatically shut off.

I suppose there's some risk of that safety system failing, and perhaps it is for this reason that gas appliances should all be checked when gas is restored. The small amount of gas leaking from a pilot that didn't shut off, but also isn't burning, could create a hazard.

As for whether you could use a flexible connector and/or make changes to the cabinetry: it seems clear the answer should be yes, so maybe I've not understood what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

If you had a shutoff for your unit's gas, then the work would be contained to your unit alone. NYC's gas code requires such a shutoff for each tenant, [NYC Fuel Gas Code 409.4](https://up.codes/viewer/new_york_city/nyc-fuel-gas-code-2022/chapter/4/gas-piping-installations#409.3):

> Where a single meter is used to supply gas to more than one building or tenant, a separate shutoff valve shall be provided for each building or tenant.

Non-dwelling units specifically get access to their shutoffs under 409.3.1, implying that it's normal for dwelling units to not have access to their shutoffs. The obvious resolution of the discrepancy between the current code and your super is that your system is "grandfathered in" from a previous code version that didn't require per-dwelling shutoffs.

Best I can tell, [NYC Fuel Gas Code 406.6.2.1.1](https://up.codes/viewer/new_york_city/nyc-fuel-gas-code-2022/chapter/4/gas-piping-installations#406.6.2.1.1) requires the re-inspection that your super was referencing:

> Any gas piping system or part thereof that has been previously energized and has been shut down shall be required to obtain a certificate of approval of gas installation for all appliances served by the affected gas meter(s) prior to the reestablishment of gas into such system.

The formal meaning of "certificate of approval of gas installation" is left pretty vague. There's language elsewhere in the code saying that these certificates never expire. I can imagine a scenario where these certificates were invented 5 years ago, so installations from earlier but not later require just the one inspection so that future work won't require *yet another* inspection.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't about the gas being turned off.  Here in NZ, the regulation is that if there is any work done, then all connections/outlets have to be tested.  So, I suspect its the same where you live.

I can think of some reasons right away

- introduced particles into the gas line that could block other outlets.
- reduced the flow rate for everyone,
- caused impurities to be sucked into the line.